# windows 7 batch file to delete and remove folders then copy entire folder (and subfolder)

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, copy, directory

It's been a long time since I've created any batch files.

What I'm trying to do is delete an entire folder, and then copy another folder (and it's sub folders and files) to the location where I deleted the original file (this is a backup process).

I've run into three problems:

1. the batch file prompts me when it runs the delete operation and this needs to happen "behind the scenes" so I can't be prompted.
2. the `del "c:\my folder location\myfoldertodelete"` only deletes the files within that folder
3. the `copy "c:\my other folder location\myotherfolder" "c:\my folder location\"` only copies the files within that folder, not the sub directories.

I assume I need xcopy or something but I've never used that.  If anyone can help me jump through these three hoops, I'd greatly appreciate it.

edit: (updating with the copy command that isn't working

```
C:\Users\Chris>copy /s "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects
\new project" "D:\VS 2010 projects\Projects\"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo y | rd /s c:\directory.to.be.removed
copy /s  c:\source c:\destination
```

Comment: ok getting closer, that does remove the entire directory, but the copy isn't working. it says "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: I just updated my OP with the command that isn't working. I also tried putting in the name of the folder to be copied in the destination and that didnt' work either.

Comment: Using `xcopy` asked me following and waited for my response: Does C:\Users\user1\Documents\Dest specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? 
After I entered D, it resumed and finished working. To see the solution on this issue, refer my solution.

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson, you might have got "the syntax of the command is incorrect", because `/s` goes with `xcopy` and not `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo y | rd /s C:\Users\user1\Documents\Dest
echo d | xcopy /s /y "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Src" "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Dest"
```

where:
"C:\Users\user1\Documents\Src" is the Source directory and
"C:\Users\user1\Documents\Dest" is the Destination directory.